# Stop 3D plots from appearing 2D

Tags: matlab, plot

When I plot a 3D plot and rotate the plot to see it from top view, Matlab plot a two dimensional plot which looks like the projection of the plot on a plane. How can I prevent that?

Here is the plot for cos(x^2+y^2) in Mathematica:

**Angled view in Mathematica:**

[image]

**Top view in Mathematica:**

[image]

As you see even at top view the **depth** of the object is visible.
In Matlab the same plot is:

**Angled view in Matlab:**

[image]

**Top view in Matlab:**

[image]

The code for Matlab's plot:

```
x = -pi:0.1:pi;
y = x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = cos(X.^2+Y.^2);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

Comment: In Mathematica it isn't the case. When you try to see the object from an angle close to the top view you see some depth, it isn't just like a projection. However, in Matlab as you get close to the top view it looks like a projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`camproj('perspective')`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/camproj.html)?

it gives you:

[image]

Comment: Fixed a minor typo in the answer. And you might be right, that this is what OP wants. I'll keep mine up there as reference, since OP mentioned "close to the top" in his comment. Anyway, +1 =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin It doesn't work for me. When I see the the plot from a top point of view it is a 2D plot.

Comment: @yashar this does work, I have tested in on your function. Maybe you just want to add some lighting in addition? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/lighting-overview.html?refresh=true

Comment: @Dan Could you please post some plots like I posted for Mathematica?

Comment: @yashar post the equation for your first plot (with the folds), and are you looking for specifically the lighting and shiny rendering? Or just the actual perspective of the projection as your question implies

Comment: @Dan I edited the question and added Matlab's code. I want to get the same top view in Matlab as I get it in Mathematica. I don't want a 2d projection of the 3D plot when I look at it from top.

Comment: @yashar so what is wrong with just using my original suggestion of `camproj('perspective')`? I've added an image, is this still not what you want?

Comment: @Dan. Sorry that was my mistake. Actually the result is not as good as that of Mathematica. When I looked at the middle of Matlab's plot I thought it was still a 2D image.

Comment: @yashar yes but that is a lighting issue, nothing to do with perspective. Matlab is just making fewer assumptions regarding how you want the data displayed. If you play around with the lighting and rendering options you can get what Mathematica is giving you. But that \wasn't your question.